# Python: Calculate number of days between two dates in different formats?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to calculate the number of days between 2006/09/21 and 2008-12-27 using Python? Note: Both dates are in different formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question has tagged `pandas` in it

```
In [30]: import pandas as pd

In [31]: d1 = pd.to_datetime("2006/09/21", format="%Y-%m-%d")

In [32]: d2 = pd.to_datetime("2008-12-27", format="%Y/%m/%d")

In [33]: (d2 - d1).days
Out[33]: 828
```

Comment: This won't work in case of the OP needs to use some other formats. In the USA the standard format is "mm/dd/yyyy" and in UK and in India the standard format is  "dd/mm/yyyy".

Comment: But OP is saying what format he needs right? And pandas datetime is good enough to parse it

Answer (score 3):

You can use `datetime`, which is in the standard library:

```
import datetime

dt1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("2008-12-27", "%Y-%m-%d")
dt2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("2006/09/21", "%Y/%m/%d")

(dt1 - dt2).days  # 828
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the `datetime.strptime()` function to convert each of these strings into datetime objects. Try the below code:

```
import datetime

d1 = '2006/09/21'
d2 = '2008-12-27'

#convert strings to datetime objects
d1_converted = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1,'%Y/%m/%d')
d2_converted = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2,'%Y-%m-%d')

#difference between two dates in days
(d2_converted - d1_converted).days #output is '828'
```

Read the docs for more information on formatting other strings: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior